# Estimating equation for plane if distances to various points on it are known

Tags: c++, math, vector, 3d

I know the distance to various points on a plane, as it is being viewed from an angle. I want to find the equation for this plane from just that information (5 to 15 different points, as many as necessary).

I will later use the equation for the plane to estimate what the distance to the plane *should* be at different points; in order to prove that it is roughly flat.

Unfortunately, a google search doesn't bring much up. :(

Comment: I believe that this might be the answer to my question:
http://jtaylor1142001.net/calcjat/Solutions/VPlanes/VP3Pts.htm

Comment: I assume you are talking about planes in 3D. There are numerous ways to define plane equation. In general, you need only 3 points to define a plane.

Comment: @Azza: 3 known points _on_ the plane (distance 0). If you have 5 points at distances `d0..d4` to the plane, you have to construct 5 spheres and find a plane which touches all 5 spheres. Far harder.

Comment: @MSalters I thought: "I know the distance to various points _on a plane_, as it is being viewed from an angle. I want to find the _equation for this plane from just that information_ (5 to 15 different points, as many as necessary)."_ means that all points are in-plane and the plane equation is needed.

Comment: @EmileVictor: No, that assumes you have `{x,y,z}` for 3 points in the plane. You only have `x²+y²+z²` (distance).

Comment: @MSalters Oh, I see. I misread "distances" as "coordinates". My bad.

Comment: @AzzA: Hmm, I'm starting to feel that the question isn't well-phrased. I think we need a picture.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8166/discussion-between-azza-and-msalters)

Answer (score 2):

If you, indeed, know **distances** and not **coordinates**, then it is ill-posed problem - there is infinite number of planes that will have points with any number of given distances from origin.

This is easy to verify. Let's take shortest distance `D0`, from set of given distances `{D0..DN-1}` , and construct a plane with normal vector `{D0,0,0}` (vector of length `D0` along `x`-axis). For each of remaining lengths we now have infinite number of points that will lie in this plane (forming circles in-plane around `(D0,0,0)` point). Moreover, we can rotate all vectors by an arbitrary angle and get a new plane.

Here is simple picture in 2D (distances to a line; it's simpler to draw ;) ).

[image]

As we can see, there are TWO points on the line for each distance `D1..DN-1` > `D0` - one is shown for `D1` and `D2`, and the two other for these distances would be placed in 4th quadrant (`+x`, `-y`). Moreover, we can rotate our line around origin by an arbitrary angle and still satisfy given distances.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to skip over the process of finding the best fit plane, it's been handled in some other answers, and talk about something else.

"Prove" takes us into statistical inference. The way this is done is you make a formal hypothesis "the surface is flat" and then see if the data supports rejecting this hypothesis at some confidence level.

So you can wind up saying "I'm not even 1% sure that the surface isn't flat" -- but you can't ever *prove* that it's flat.

Answer (score 0):

Geometry? Sounds like a job for math.SE! What form will the equation take? Will it be a plane?

I will assume you want an accurate solution.

1. Find the absolute positions with geometry
2. Make a best fit regression line in C++ in 2 of the 3 dimensions.

Comment: Sounds like way overly complicated way to solve, when OP actually has 3+ points already in-plane.

Comment: My understanding is that the OP doesn't have a plane, but a skater of points from which he wants to make a plane?